# User specified substitution regex in python

Tags: python, regex

Working on a simple script processing text files and logs. It has to take from the command line a list of regular expression for substitutions. For example:

```
./myscript.py --replace=s/foo/bar/ --replace=s@/etc/hosts@/etc/foo@ --replace=@test\@email.com@root\@email.com@
```

Is there a simple way to provide a user specified substitution pattern to the python re library? And have that pattern run against a string? Any elegant solution?

If possible, I'd like to avoid writing my own parser. Note that I'd like support for modifiers like /g or /i and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to write your own parser to parse `s/foo/bar/g` into `regex, replacewith, flags`, and to handle escaping of separators.

Comment: At this point, wouldn't it be easier to just use sed?

Comment: Once you split the substitution pattern into its pattern and replacement parts, you can use `re.compile()` to create the regexp object.

Comment: @ChrisCorley: this is part of a larger script, I'd rather not have to shell out to sed to do the replacement.

I was really hoping to be able to avoid writing my own parser. Supporting arbitrary options and escaping so not to complicate the rest of the regular expression looks non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the comments, you can use `re.compile()`, but that only works for `match`ing and `search`ing apparently. Assuming you have only substitutions, you might do something like this:

```
modifiers_map = {
    'i': re.IGNORE,
    ...
}

for replace in replacements:
    # Look for a generalized separator in front of a command
    m = re.match(r'(s?)(.)([^\2]+)\2([^\2]+)\2([ig]*)', replace)
    if not m:
        print 'Invalid command: %s' % replace
        continue
    command, separator, query, substitution, modifiers = m.groups()
    # Convert the modifiers to flags
    flags = reduce(operator.__or__, [modifiers_map[char] for char in modifiers], 0)
    # This needs a little bit of tweaking if you want to support
    # group matching (like \1, \2, etc.). This also assumes that
    # you're only getting 's' as a command
    my_text = re.sub(query, substitution, my_text, flags=flags)
```

Suffice it to say, this is a rough draft but I think it'd get you 90% of the way to what you're looking for.

Comment: `re.compile()` returns object that has `.match`, `.search`, `.sub`, `.finditer`, etc methods. `[^\1]` won't work: it is equivalent to `[^c]` where `ord(c) == 1`. Also the regex doesn't handle escaped separator. `g` flag is default in Python so `modifiers_map` won't handle its absence.

Comment: That's good to know about `re.compile()` -- I would have though it weird if they'd only supported the search commands :-)

Comment: However, while `'[^\1]'` may refer to the character, `r'[^\1]'` refers to the group: `re.match(r'(s?)(.)([^\2]+)\2([^\2]+)\2([ig]*)', 's@foo@bar@i').groups()` would be a quick way to see that

Comment: Try `re.DEBUG` to see the expression e.g., `re.match(r'(.)[^\1]', 'aa', re.DEBUG)` is not `None` unlike `re.match(r'(.)[^a]', 'aa', re.DEBUG)`.

Comment: Ah. Well now I feel like a jerk :-) I hadn't used `re.DEBUG` but clearly very useful -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a space as a separator to exploit shell's command-line parser:

```
$ myscript --replace=foo bar \
>          --replace=/etc/hosts /etc/foo gi \
>          --replace=test@email.com root@email.com
```

`g` flag is default in Python so you need to add special support for it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from functools import partial

all_re_flags = 'Lgimsux' # regex flags
parser = ArgumentParser(usage='%(prog)s [--replace PATTERN REPL [FLAGS]]...')
parser.add_argument('-e', '--replace', action='append', nargs='*')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.replace)

subs = [] # replacement functions: input string -> result
for arg in args.replace:
    count = 1 # replace only the first occurrence if no `g` flag
    if len(arg) == 2:
        pattern, repl = arg
    elif len(arg) == 3:
        pattern, repl, flags = arg
        if ''.join(sorted(flags)) not in all_re_flags:
            parser.error('invalid flags %r for --replace option' % flags)
        if 'g' in flags: # add support for `g` flag
            flags = flags.replace('g', '')
            count = 0 # replace all occurrences
        if flags: # embed flags
            pattern = "(?%s)%s" % (flags, pattern)
    else:
        parser.error('wrong number of arguments for --replace option')
    subs.append(partial(re.compile(pattern).sub, repl, count=count))
```

You could use `subs` as follows:

```
input_string = 'a b a b'
for replace in subs:
    print(replace(input_string))
```

Example:

```
$ ./myscript -e 'a b' 'no flag' -e 'a B' 'with flags' ig
```

Output:

```
[['a b', 'no flag'], ['a B', 'with flags', 'ig']]
no flag a b
with flags with flags
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. Given the complexity of any of the proposed solutions and the lack of a pre-backed parser in the standard libraries, I just went the extra mile and implemented my own parser.

It is not significantly more complex than the other proposals, see below. I just need to write tests now.

Thanks!

```
class Replacer(object):
  def __init__(self, patterns=[]):
    self.patterns = []
    for pattern in patterns:
      self.AddPattern(pattern)

  def ParseFlags(self, flags):
    mapping = {
      'g': 0, 'i': re.I, 'l': re.L, 'm': re.M, 's': re.S, 'u': re.U, 'x': re.X,
      'd': re.DEBUG
    }

    result = 0
    for flag in flags:
      try:
        result |= mapping[flag]
      except KeyError:
        raise ValueError(
            "Invalid flag: %s, known flags: %s" % (flag, mapping.keys()))
    return result

  def Apply(self, text):
    for regex, repl in self.patterns:
      text = regex.sub(repl, text)
    return text

  def AddPattern(self, pattern):
    separator = pattern[0]
    match = []
    for position, char in enumerate(pattern[1:], start=1):
      if char == separator:
        if pattern[position - 1] != '\\':
          break
        match[-1] = separator
        continue
      match += char
    else:
      raise ValueError("Invalid pattern: could not find divisor.")

    replacement = []
    for position, char in enumerate(pattern[position + 1:], start=position + 1):
      if char == separator:
        if pattern[position - 1] != '\\':
          break
        replacement[-1] = separator
        continue
      replacement += char
    else:
      raise ValueError(
          "Invalid pattern: could not find divisor '%s'." % separator)

    flags = self.ParseFlags(pattern[position + 1:])
    match = ''.join(match)
    replacement = ''.join(replacement)
    self.patterns.append((re.compile(match, flags=flags), replacement))
```

Comment: It produces the same result with/without `g` flag (you should probably replace only the first match if no `g` is given). It doesn't handle even number of escape chars (to escape the escape char).